# SQL to REQL how to?

Tags: python, sql, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, reql

I'm new to Reql and i'm trying to figure out how to transform my simple Sql request to Reql (i'm using python with rethinkdb)

```
Select id, min(value), max(value), avg(value)
From mytable
Group by id
Having timestamp between '2003-12-05T15:01:00.05Z' and '2003-12-05T15:05:00.05Z'
```

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python so I answer in JavaScript. You can try this in Dashboard and convert to Python easily I think.

First, create an index:

```
r.table('mytable').indexCreate('timestamp')
```

With that index, we can use `between` to filter data then group like this:

```
r
  .table('mytable')
  .between(r.time(2013, 12, 5, 15, 1, 0, 'Z'),
           r.time(2013, 12, 5, 15, 5, 0, 'Z'),
           {index: 'timestamp'})
  .group('id')
  .ungroup()
  .map(function(doc) {
    return 
      {
        id: doc('group'),
        min: doc('reduction')('value').min(),
        max: doc('reduction')('value').max(),
        avg: doc('reduction')('value').avg(),
      }
  })
```

Comment: i'm trying to transform it to python syntax but 'doc' doesn't exist on python, stuck with that for now...

Comment: @BitFlow it's a lambda, so that should be the param. I guess it looks like this in Python `map(lambda doc: {'id': doc['group'], 'min': doc['reduction']['value'].min()})`. Looks at this page: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/map/

Comment: Worked like a charm :D thank you kureikain, i should search for a good tutorial